# Retrofit get duplicate header while use dynamic header

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am trying to upload photo to server, everything quite good until retrofit duplicate my header pass by param into method.

I have use HeaderMap too but still get duplicate

```
public class ImageUploadHelper implements ImageUpload {

private static final int PERCENT_QUALITY = 100;

private Service mService;

public ImageUploadHelper(Retrofit retrofit) {
    mService = retrofit.create(Service.class);
}

private Observable<RequestBody> createUploadFunction(File file) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        try {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, PERCENT_QUALITY, stream);
            byte[] buffer = stream.toByteArray();
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody
                    .create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), buffer);
            emitter.onNext(requestBody);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            emitter.onError(e);
        }
        emitter.onComplete();
    });
}

//@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public Observable<ImageUploadResponse> uploadImage(String rule, File file, Integer confirmId) {
    Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    String fileNames = file.getName();
    Observable<RequestBody> func = createUploadFunction(file);
    return func.flatMap(rb -> {
        String header = "name=file; filename=" + fileNames;
        return mService.uploadImage( rule,
                header,
                Integer.toString(confirmId),
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()),
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude()),
                rb );
    });
}


interface Service {
    @Headers({"Content-Type: image/png"})
    @POST("query/{rule}/transaction/confirm/image")
    Observable<ImageUploadResponse> uploadImage(
            @Path("rule") String rule,
            @Header("Content-Disposition") String contentDisposition,
            @Header("Confirm-Id") String confirmId,
            @Header("Latitude") String latitude,
            @Header("Longitude") String longitude,
            @Body RequestBody photo);

}

}
```

> - I/NetModule: Content-Type: image/png
> - I/NetModule: Content-Length:    698803
> - I/NetModule: Content-Disposition: name=file;filename=1553668305157.jpg
> - I/NetModule: Confirm-Id: 764
> - I/NetModule: Latitude: 0.0
> - I/NetModule: Longitude: 0.0
> - I/NetModule: Content-Disposition: name=file;filename=1553668305157.jpg
> - I/NetModule: Confirm-Id: 764
> - I/NetModule: Latitude: 0.0
> - I/NetModule: Longitude: 0.0    I/NetModule: Authorization: Bearer    OToyZThiZWUzM2E4ZjQ1NzllODhkZjg0N2JkNmRmNjFkMGZhZTc1ZDQ4
>     I/NetModule: --> END POST (binary 698803-byte body omitted)
>     I/NetModule: <-- 200 OK   I/NetModule: Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019
>     06:32:01 GMT  I/NetModule: Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.7
>     I/NetModule: Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8
>     I/NetModule: Allow: POST, OPTIONS  I/NetModule: X-Frame-Options:
>     SAMEORIGIN  I/NetModule: Content-Length: 75  I/NetModule: <-- END
>     HTTP (binary 75-byte body omitted)

Comment: Can you share your API details where you are posting the image data? Don't forget to hide your domain information.

Comment: @OmarFaroqueAnik i can't get that code. My lead team is off few day and i can't find solution for this problem. But i don't think API is problem, Ios can upload image with that API